# Docker not running entrypoint .sh script

Tags: postgresql, docker, yaml

I'm trying to build a docker-compose to set up a postgres database with an initial script that creates some tables there.

I have this docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3.9'
services:
    postgres:
        image: postgres:12.7
        #restart: always
        environment:
          - POSTGRES_USER=postgres
          - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=postgres
        logging:
          options:
            max-size: 10m
            max-file: "3"
        ports:
          - '5438:5432'
        volumes: 
          - ./postgres-data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
          # copy the sql script to create tables
          #- ./sql/create_tables.sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/create_tables.sql
          - ./sql/create_tables.sh:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/create_tables.sh
```

this is the `create_tables.sh`:

```
#!/bin/bash          
echo Start Executing SQL commands
psql -U postgres -f create_tables.sql
```

And the error log:

```
postgres_1 | psql: error: create_tables.sql: No such file or directory
```

Uncommenting the line `- ./sql/create_tables.sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/create_tables.sql` and commenting the line `- ./sql/create_tables.sh:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/create_tables.sh` make it work but I have to use the .sh.

My dockerfile:

```
FROM postgres:12.7

#WORKDIR ./sql/

ADD ./sql/create_tables.sql ./docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/create_tables.sql

ADD ./sql/create_tables.sh ./docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/create_tables.sh

RUN ./docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/create_tables.sh
```

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong? Thanks!!

Comment: Wouldn't uncommenting both lines be the solution here? You need both files (the .sh and .sql) to be present for the shell script to run the sql script. Perhaps I'm misunderstanding though.

Comment: That shell script doesn't do anything the `postgres` image entrypoint script doesn't already do, so I might only inject the SQL script.

Comment: Yes! That would be a solution, but I need to be executed as a .sh :(

I also edited the dockerfile but it's the same:

FROM postgres:12.7

#WORKDIR ./sql/

ADD ./sql/create_tables.sql ./docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/create_tables.sql
r
ADD ./sql/create_tables.sh ./docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/create_tables.sh

RUN ./docker-entypoint-initdb.d/create_tables.sh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to use this script below, pointing to your ".SQL" files folder in the volumes step.
It will automatically create the database and execute each SQL file inside this folder. You don't need a separate .sh file to migrate/create/execute your SQL commands using the docker-compose with the correct volume command.

```
version: '3.9'
services:
    postgres:
        image: postgres:12.7
        #restart: always
        environment:
          - POSTGRES_USER=postgres
          - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=postgres
        logging:
          options:
            max-size: 10m
            max-file: "3"
        ports:
          - '5438:5432'
        volumes: 
          - ./postgres-data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
          # copy the sql script to create tables
          #- ./sql/create_tables.sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/create_tables.sql
          #- ./sql/create_tables.sh:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/create_tables.sh
          - ./sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d #put all .SQL files inside sql/ folder and all files will be executed.
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer Paulo, I found it very insightful. Regrettably, I have the restriction to do it by an .sh. When I uncomment both lines (.sql and .sh), both gets executed, but using just .sh, it's like the .sql is not being moved to the container.

Comment: No problem Racofernandez, I got your point, but It's easier if you leave the ".sh" file aside and use as I said, you use fewer commands and get the same result: the creation of your database with tables.

Comment: Totally right Paulo! 

Finally I separate a sql folder and a sh folder and it worked. I will upvote your answer as it's the most appropiate solution

- ./db-init-scripts/create_tables.sh:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/init.sh
- ./sql:/sql

Answer (score 1):

Finally I separate a sql folder and a sh folder and it worked, but the correct approach would be Paulo answer.

```
 - ./db-init-scripts/create_tables.sh:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/init.sh 
 - ./sql:/sql
```